# How to use 'drag n drop' movement on a tabstrip to a form in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, events, tabs, drag-and-drop

I have a userform which includes a tabstrip with several tabs. I tried to check if I can change the tabs's order using "drag n drop" movements.

To accomplish this, I tried to check if a `TabStrip1_BeforeDropOrPaste` event can be fired, while trying to use 'drag n drop' with intention to change a tab's order.

e.g. I tryied to move the fifth tab between the second and the forth with intention to make it the third one.

I used the following piece of code:

```
Private Sub TabStrip1_BeforeDropOrPaste(ByVal Index As Long, ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, ByVal Action As MSForms.fmAction, ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    MsgBox "event fired!"
End Sub
```

but the event was not fired. (the messagebox did not show up)

Is there a way to fire the `TabStrip1_BeforeDropOrPaste` this way? If my approach is completly wrong, any ideas on how to accomplish my goal using another structure?

Comment: `BeforeDropOrPaste` fires at the drop *target*.  My guess is that it didn't fire because AFAIK the TabStrip isn't a drag *source*.  I'd look for a 3rd party control instead.

Comment: thanks for your tips.